# Is it acceptable on Stack Overflow to insult someone if you delete the post anyway?

Tags: discussion, harassment

I noticed that it is possible to insult someone in a post or in the posts comment section and then delete the post. In such a case, the post is gone and it cannot be flagged anymore.

Is it acceptable on Stack Overflow to insult someone if you delete the post anyway?

Comment: Just flag it and move on.

Comment: Once is a coincidence, twice is the start of a pattern. It can help to check out a posting history to see if this is something that happens more often. If not... maybe just have pity on them for having reasons to act out like a childish jerk.

Comment: Great. Also, just for your info, mods cannot see who down/upvoted either, but if they have reasonably strong suspicions, they can ask a Stack Overflow employee to run a database query.

Comment: To help people understand why people do things like this, and that most of the time it has nothing to do with you.  [Blame Video](https://www.voicetube.com/videos/22510)  Note: I agonized over posting this, but it really helped me understand and not worry about other people's seemingly irrational behavior.  Realizing it is not about me most of the time.

Comment: It is **not** acceptable on SO to insult anybody regardless of the reason.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

No, insulting someone and then deleting the offending post (or comment) is not acceptable.

Raise a custom flag against another of their posts explaining the situation and a moderator will look into it. If you have a screenshot that would be a help, but we can see deleted content. If there aren't any other, undeleted posts by the user then you'll have to raise a flag against one your own posts will do. In such cases it's really important to make it clear why you are flagging your own post.

If the moderator agrees that your flag is valid then action will be taken. I'm not going to say exactly what action as that will depend on the circumstances.

Comment: Circumstances based responses seem fair. E.g., are they having a bad day so that this is a one-off or is there a history?

Comment: Seems like intentionally insulting somebody is unacceptable, regardless of whether the offending post or comment is subsequently deleted.

Comment: And the "having a bad day" excuse doesn't wash either.

Comment: if the circumstances are that insults are going on both way, maybe the "action" will go both way too :P

Comment: "Raise a custom flag *against another of their posts*" but what to do when along with deleted answer we lose link to authors profile? My guess is we should custom-flag one of our *own* posts, describe situation and provide link to question which earlier held that answer.

Comment: @Pshemo I did assume that there were other, undeleted posts by the user. If there aren't then raising on against one your own posts will do. In such cases it's really important to make it clear why you are flagging your own post.

Comment: Yes, but to be clear I am referring to situation where there are no more posts from that user *withing current question*. There may be many other posts all over Stack Overflow but without link to user profile (which will be removed along with that one answer where we noticed bad behavior) we may not be able to locate other posts to flag.

Comment: Both flagging a different post and flagging ones own post seem especially susceptible to miscommunication from the outset—as is more or less acknowledged in the answer above:  "it's really important to make it clear why you are flagging your own post"

While it would probably work it's not very satisfying to put additional onus on a person who is trying to do right by the site.

Comment: @StephenC Until it's you having a bad day, and you would like people to understand your intentions are not malicious.

Comment: Nope.  It is still not an excuse.  Even for me.  This is about someone being intentionally insulting.  (And "It wasn't my intention to be malicious" is as lame as "I haven't got a racist bone in my body".)

Comment: @StephenC It might be lame but it happens and I believe it happened to everyone at some point whether on SO or somewhere else because, well, nobody is perfect and I don't think that shooting such person would be beneficial otherwise we all would be...

Answer (score 34):

[Chris](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387196/6451573) recommendation is in order, but you also probably know that when you flag a rude comment (containing swear words that pass through the automatic filter), moderators delete it in 100% of the cases.

In that case a moderator (and not the poster) deleted the comment after several users (including you) flagged it as "harassment/abuse".

So in this case, moderators were in the loop and can take appropriate action (one of the actions would be to contact community managers to have "a**hole" added to the automatic rude words, since it doesn't seem to be the case now)

To sum it up, if you had a chance to flag the comment and it gets deleted, don't worry about it.